# Access variable from Constants.h Class

Tags: swift3, constants

I have created a new class **Constants.h** and define URL to access it globally in the app.

```
#ifndef Constants_h
#define Constants_h

#define LoginUrl      @"http://dev.abc.in/app/login"

#endif
```

But in the viewcontroller it doesn't give access to constants. or Is there any other way to define constants in Swift as I have done successfully in objective c, but getting issue using Swift. Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: have you included Constant.h in Bridging header?

Comment: @adarshaU Why do we need to add the class in Bridging header

Comment: bridging header required to add objective c file into swift..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Objective-C code in Swift you need to include the headers for the Objective-C code in your bridging header. The Swift compiler translates all of the declarations in the bridging header and imports them into Swift. To fix your issue, just import the `Constants.h` file in your bridging header.

You can also create global constants in Swift, just by writing the variable definition in global scope.